# predicted survival curve in R- Parametric method

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to create predicted survival plots for survreg or flexsurvreg in R. But I am getting errors for the plot when I use more than one predictors in the survreg. I would like to try it using flexsurvreg or survreg, For lung data set, I used the following code to fit the model.

```
require(survival)
s <- with(lung,Surv(time,status))

sWei  <- survreg(s ~ as.factor(sex)+age+ph.ecog+wt.loss+ph.karno,dist='weibull',data=lung)

fitKM <- survfit(s ~ sex,data=lung)
plot(fitKM)

lines(predict(sWei, newdata=list(sex=1),type="quantile",p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)),seq(.99,.01,by=-.01),col="blue")
lines(predict(sWei, newdata=list(sex=2),type="quantile",p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)),seq(.99,.01,by=-.01),col="red")
```

I am getting errors when I use the above command for plotting. Please let me know where I am doing wrong when plotting for predicted survival curve.

```
> lines(predict(sWei, newdata=list(sex=1),type="quantile",p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)),seq(.99,.01,by=-.01),col="red")
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'age' not found
```

Comment: You are using many variables in your model. When creating `newdata`, you need to create values for all variables in the model.

Comment: Thanks Roman. In my model, I have to use many variables, is there another way to create the survival curve after adjusting for many variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to give values in the `list` to every variable in your model, so that it can plot the curve.

```
require(survival)
s <- with(lung,Surv(time,status))

sWei  <- survreg(s ~ as.factor(sex)+age+ph.ecog+wt.loss+ph.karno,dist='weibull',data=lung)

fitKM <- survfit(s ~ sex,data=lung)
plot(fitKM)

lines(predict(sWei, newdata=list(sex=1, 
                                 age = 1, 
                                 ph.ecog = 1, 
                                 ph.karno = 90,
                                 wt.loss = 2),
                                 type="quantile",
                                 p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)),
                                 seq(.99,.01,by=-.01),
                                 col="blue")
lines(predict(sWei, newdata=list(sex=2, 
                                 age = 1, 
                                 ph.ecog = 1, 
                                 ph.karno = 90,
                                 wt.loss = 2),
                                 type="quantile",
                                 p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)),
                                 seq(.99,.01,by=-.01),
                                 col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Did you just assign age=1, or is there another reason.

Comment: @Mani You're very welcome. `age` and the other variables have to have a value, but I didn't have any particular reason for choosing the values that I did. I took it that you wanted to see the effect of `sex` so I just set the others arbitrarily and kept everything except for `sex` the same between the blue and red curves.